# Why is order of arguments in cmp instruction important?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I wonder why `cmp` instruction requires certain condition for order of arguments.

For example, I have tried both of these.

1. `cmpl %eax, $'A'`
2. `cmpl $'A', %eax`

First line returned error, saying operand type mismatch.
Second line worked well.

I went through Intel IA-32 manual, but it couldn't answer my question. It just said subtraction between argument 1 and 2, not which types each arguments should have.

I want to know why the first line of code returned operand type mismatch, but second line didn't.

Comment: The Intel manual makes clear that the first operand must be either a register or a memory operand. Since you're using AT&T syntax the operands are given in reverse order, and `$'A'` is neither a register nor a memory operand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The machine-code instruction only supports that direction with an immediate.  If you didn't find this, you were looking in the wrong place.  Intel's vol.2 manual details every available encoding for every instruction.  [Here's an HTML extract of the entry for `cmp`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmp).

---

Remember that assembly limitations aren't arbitrary source-level choices; it's not a language like C++, it's a way of describing machine code.

Most ALU instructions write their destination (especially instructions that date back to original 8086), so it can't be an immediate.  e.g. `sub %eax, $123` obviously makes no sense.  **So consistency of machine-code formats / ease of decoding is one reason for not having a special `cmp` opcode with an immediate "destination".**  It would also be irregular for assembly syntax, if assemblers mapped that opcode to the same `cmp` mnemonic instead of a different reverse-cmp mnemonic.

By contrast, `cmp r/m32, r32` and `cmp r32, r/m32` both exist, so you can compare memory to a register in either direction.  Again, this is consistent with the patterns of other ALU instructions like `add` and `sub`, so this also makes sense for more "regular" decoding / patterns in the machine code.

If you're branching on the result with `jcc` you can always swap the operands and use the opposite condition.  Sometimes you'd like to have CF set a certain way to feed `adc` or `sbb`, though, so yes occasionally this is an inconvenience.

But that wasn't sufficient reason for the architect of 8086's instruction set, Stephen Morse, to use one of the few unused opcodes for a reverse-compare with immediate encoding of `cmp`.

---

**What could have made sense is a reverse-subtract or reverse-compare instruction like ARM has** (i.e. `dst = src - dst` rather than `dst -= src`), but x86's variable-length machine-code format means there are only so many 1-byte opcodes.  That could have been just one more "normal" immediate ALU instruction.

Or actually 5 more opcodes, including 2 dedicated bytes if we follow the pattern of normal ALU instructions: normal `op r/m8, imm8`, `op r/m16, sign_extended_imm8`, `op r/m16, imm16` and the AL,imm8 and AX,imm16 short forms (with no ModRM byte).  I guess for non-immediate operands, the mnemonic could be an alias for `cmp` with the operands reversed, so we don't also need those 4 opcodes (8 and 16-bit in both directions).

ARM came later and used a fixed-width 32-bit instruction word, so there was quite a bit of opcode encoding space to use on useful instructions like reverse-compare and reverse-subtract.